# Why Jenkins Maven build failed due to HTTP Basic Authentication?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

From command line I can execute `mvn clean install deploy` with out any extra configuration with maven-3.2.2. So there is no doubt about configuration of maven setting. My private repository `http://maven.medicom.com.sa/maven2/releases` accessible via maven although there is an `basic http` authentication enabled. As bellow is snapshot of `setting.xml` files. While I tried it with Jenkins Maven plugins its unable to access `http://maven.medicom.com.sa/maven2/releases` repository due to `basic http` authentication.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
        <id>medicom</id>
        <configuration>
            <httpHeaders>
                <property>
                    <name>Authorization</name>
                    <value>Basic bXE2ZX46bXVkaXMhcB==</value>
                </property>
            </httpHeaders>
        </configuration>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>medicom.plugins</id>
        <configuration>
            <httpHeaders>
                <property>
                    <name>Authorization</name>
                    <value>Basic bXE2ZX46bXVkaXMhcB==</value>
                </property>
            </httpHeaders>
        </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>medicom.releases</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                 <name>medicom.releases</name>
                 <value>!false</value>
              </property>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>medicom</id>
                    <url>http://maven.medicom.com.sa/maven2/releases</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>medicom.plugins</id>
                    <url>http://maven.medicom.com.sa/maven2/releases</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: And you are sure Jenkins is using the same settings.xml file as you do when you run the goal locally?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins maven plugin unable to `basic http authentication` via server configuration. So you must skip such type of configuration for Jenkins CI.

```
<configuration>
    <httpHeaders>
        <property>
            <name>Authorization</name>
            <value>Basic bXE2ZX46bXVkaXMhcB==</value>
        </property>
    </httpHeaders>
</configuration>
```

Rather you should use username and password:

```
<username>maven</username>
<password>password</password>
```

As below commented line must be removed:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
        <id>medicom</id>
        <!-- <configuration>
            <httpHeaders>
                <property>
                    <name>Authorization</name>
                    <value>Basic bXE2ZX46bXVkaXMhcB==</value>
                </property>
            </httpHeaders>
        </configuration> -->
        <username>maven</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>medicom.plugins</id>
        <!-- <configuration>
            <httpHeaders>
                <property>
                    <name>Authorization</name>
                    <value>Basic bXE2ZX46bXVkaXMhcB==</value>
                </property>
            </httpHeaders>
        </configuration> -->
        <username>maven</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>medicom.releases</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                 <name>medicom.releases</name>
                 <value>!false</value>
              </property>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>medicom</id>
                    <url>http://maven.medicom.com.sa/maven2/releases</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>medicom.plugins</id>
                    <url>http://maven.medicom.com.sa/maven2/releases</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```